# switch on angularjs validation from directive

Tags: angularjs

the standard angularjs validation just works:

```
<form name="myForm"><input name="name" ng-model="name" ng-minlength="10"/></form>
```

but I can not turn it on from my directive:

```
<form name="myForm"><input name="name" ng-model="c.name" dynval /></form>

.directive('dynval', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      attr.$set('ng-minlength', 100);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but have you tried `attr.$set('ngMinlength',100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

One: you need to set it using camelCase, `attr.$set('ngMinlength', 100);`

Second: Since you're modifying the element, do it on the compile function.

Here is a live [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HstJyYULYhwolmebIfkA?p=preview)

Comment: thanks! any idea why the form is valid when the input field is empty ?